# Warning: Illegal string offset in PHP

Tags: php, string, function

I want to print out the data of users with an inner join but it won't work. The array is filled up correctly in the function and before the `foreach` but it keeps telling me:

> Warning: Illegal string offset in PHP

THE ARRAY BEFORE THE FOREACH

```
array (size=6)
  'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Vandenbergh' (length=11)
  'surname' => string 'Jan' (length=3)
  'avatar' => string '1394041001.jpg' (length=21)
  'member_id' => string '21' (length=2)
  'group_id' => string '18' (length=2)
```

FUNCTION

```
public function getMembersInfo($group_id)
{
    var_dump($group_id);
    $db = new Db();
    $select = "SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.surname, u.avatar, g.member_id, g.user_id, g.group_id FROM tblusers u INNER JOIN tblgroup_member g ON u.user_id = g.user_id WHERE g.group_id=" . $group_id .  "";

//  $result = $db->conn->query($select);
    //return $data=$result->fetch_assoc();

    $result = $db->conn->query($select);

$result_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    var_dump($result_data);
return $result_data;

}
```

PHP

```
$memberinfo = $group->getMembersInfo($group_id);
var_dump($memberinfo);


 <?php 
        var_dump($memberinfo)   ;
      foreach ($memberinfo as $info) {
            echo "<p>" . $info['name'] . $info['surname'] . "</p>";

      }

        ?>
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is hard for you to understand? Can you share? And in your analysis you have not shared what `var_dump($info)` gets you inside the `foreach`. Perhaps you expect an array, but it's a string like the error message says?

Comment: The answer is simple: You iterate over one user - more exactly about all properties of that user. You propbably want to iterate over users instead. To come around that, use concrete types you load from the database. PDO has support for that.

Comment: Please make an effort to remove profanity from your test data next time you post to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only getting one array from your `getMembersInfo` method, not an array of arrays. So, when you write `foreach ($memberinfo as $info)`, you're iterating over just one row from your database.

Comment out the lines for yourself, and see:

```
var_dump($memberinfo);
//foreach ($memberinfo as $info) {
    $info = $memberinfo;
    echo "<p>" . $info['name'] . $info['surname'] . "</p>";
//}
```

To fix this, either remove the `foreach` loop, or append the results from your MySQL query inside the `getMembersInfo()` method into an array.